# I asked a really, really stupid question

Tags: discussion

I mean, seriously, beyond obvious.

BUT, as far as I can tell, it's an original one.

Curious as to whether or not I should delete said stupid question (and the impressively polite response), or leave it there for the tiny chance that anyone will EVER AGAIN be so astoundingly lazy...

Comment: Is it the Dr. Racket one?  I wouldn't worry about it.  It's got an upvoted answer and your checkmark on it, so it's not eligible for deletion anyway.

Comment: Ah ok.  Technically it's the 1st Dr Racket question.  Should I edit it out with an explanation, or just leave it?  Question 2 will probably prove useful to some...

Comment: The answer already refers to question 1.  If you edit it out, the answer won't make any sense.

Comment: Of all the stupid questions I've seen on SO, this is one of the best.  It shall shine forever as a beacon of quality dumb.

Comment: If anything I would leave it in place and exclaim "I made that!" ... wait ...

Comment: The title needs help, but it's _far_ from the stupidest question I've seen.

Comment: When I post a stupid question (just for fun) it gets downvotes... So I have to remove it, before someone answers - or I can't remove it anymore.

Comment: The question doesn't seem that dump. What's the problem? Keep it.

Comment: Still, you should not ask two questions in one question, please. If you have two questions, that means you should ask two questions :).

Comment: @kapa Ah, that's a good point :)

Comment: Well, that's exactly why I left [my terrible meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262258) up, if you substitute "not well thought out" for "lazy". If it saves someone else the embarrassment of asking what I asked, it's worth it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Meh… there are worse. And n00bs will forever be duplicating your question if deprived of your question's answer. Rule of thumb: If it's on-topic and will help the community it should stay. If it will help you (and is on topic), it *probably* will also help the community, so that isn't a problem.

Comment: Answers to <fixmycode> questions will also help the asker; doesn't mean it will help others in any way though.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, but most questions aren't <fixmycode> questions. Edited, anyway.

Comment: @bjb568: "most questions aren't <fixmycode> questions"? Have you ever been to StackOverflow? :-) The vast majority of new questions are "What's wrong with my code?" or "How do I fix this syntax error?" or something similar.

Comment: @Ken If you filter out all questions from users with less than 200 reputation, that thins out. We're talking about i_made_that, not everybody.

Comment: Neither your answer or your comment says that they are specifically addressed to questions by i_made_that; your comment says generically "most questions". You did see the smiley though? And filtering out users less than 200 rep means that you're missing a large part of "most questions" in the first place, which are typically asked by new/low rep users.

Comment: Anyway, doesn't "and is on topic" rule out those?