# Proposed: a wiki post listing non-sx sites where broad questions are welcome

Tags: discussion, scope, new-users, community-wiki

Edit: the community rejected this idea, and I agree that the reasons
cited have merit. I've left the post up for the edification of any
future users who are considering the same idea.

In an answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262055), user [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) pointed out:

> There are plenty of places on the internet where people can go to ask
>     programming questions without being held to a standard.

It occurs to me that it could be very useful to have **one** wiki post
that lists such places, along with useful metadata such as what they
cover, how friendly or hostile they are, and what level of learner would
benefit most from using them.

When people ask broad questions like the one that prompted that
conversation, commenters could direct them to that post, for example:

> This question is too open-ended for our format. Please review the
>     guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). A listing of other places on the web that answer
>     broad questions like this can be found [here](link to that post).

Do we already have such a post? I searched but was not sure what terms
to use. If we do create such a post, it would be useful for the help
center to link to it; e.g., from "[What types of questions should I avoid
asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)".

A related question:
[Where do you post questions that are not "permitted" in StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253185)

Comment: If that won't be a spam-magnet... Also "much too broad" and "primarily opinion based" of course.

Comment: Why should such a list be hosted here? Why do people keep insisting that SE should *everything*?

Comment: Nothing to do with SO. People should find these sites themselves. Of course you can post a list on your blog to help them out, but why would SO do that? Being a quality Q&A site about programming.

Comment: In the end SE is a business, so why should the business be giving free advertising to other businesses.  Plus if someone goes there and has a bad experience, they'll blame SE for "recommending" it.  Plus everyone in the world will post their own "this is the best site ever" answer so the question itself would be off-topic list question and would have to be posted on one of the forums that the post itself is recommending.

Comment: Actually, there used to be one. But it's gone now. Probably for good reason, as who could hope to maintain such a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would suffer from exactly the same issue as recommendation questions:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract **opinionated answers and spam**. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

My emphasis.

The other aspect is that their answers tend to go out of date very quickly as new resources come on line. If you had this list then it would need to be actively curated to ensure that it was always up to date and that the resources linked to still did what people thought they did.

Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a list repository.